# How to invoke a method an the child class when argument is of type parent class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, subclass

I have the following code (simplified):

```
#include <cstdio>

class parent
{
public:
  virtual void do_something() const
  {
    printf("hello I'm the parent class\n");
  }
};

class child : public parent 
{
public:
  virtual void do_something() const
  {
    printf("hello I'm the child class\n");
  }
};

void handle(parent p)
{
   p.do_something();
}

int main()
{
  child c;
  handle(c);
  return 0;
}
```

This prints `hello I'm the parent class`, even though I passed a argument of type `child`. How can I tell C++ to behave like Java does and invoke the method of the child, printing `hello I'm the child class`?

Comment: `base` class is the even more commonly used term.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accept the argument by reference (or, probably, const reference):

```
void handle (parent & p)
//        note this ^
{
    p.do_something();
}
```

In your case, [*slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) happens: the `parent` part of the `child` gets extracted as a separate object of type `parent` and goes to the function.

If you want to put different subclasses into a single collection, a usual solution is to use smart pointers, such as [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: The problem is that in the "big" code I am inserting the object into a `vector`, but there can be different subclasses in the same `vector`. Can I store those references in the vector?

Comment: @msrd0, no, you can't store references in the vector. You'd have to use `std::unique_ptr` as your vector element type, and store pointers to dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: In addition to @SergeyA's suggestion, you can also use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Comment: @RSahu, this will unlikely to fly - it's hard to imagine all those automatic objecs will have a lifetime exceeding vector lifetime...

Comment: @SergeyA Actually, I've seen such use cases, but I agree that they are rare.